# Android - Issue with the Android's back button

Tags: android

Hi
I have written a little program that will open the default browser and direct to an URL. My problem is that when I click Android's back button, it will return to a blank page, how can I change it to exit the program instead of return to a blank page

The code for reference:

```
package com.example.helloandroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       Intent httpIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
       httpIntent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.bbc.co.uk/"));

       startActivity(httpIntent);   
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this line:

```
finish();
```

after your line startActivity(httpIntent);
The black page is your activity, which is not set any content.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your main activity? 
If it is, I can't see the onDestroy method in it. That might be the reason. Try getting it by clicking the right button on the main class page and going to Source>Override Implement Methods, and adding the onDestroy(bundle) to your class.

I think that should solve your problem!